# System.Management.Automation.Powershell returns Empty collection of PSObjects when running cmdlet Get-NetNeighbor

Tags: c#, powershell

I am using `System.Management.Automation.Powershell` for a project, and I'm trying to get a list of HostNames on the network. Found a thing that can get me HostNames out of IPs, but when I got to get all active IPs on the network, the command `Get-NetNeighbor` gives absolutely no return.

```cs
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript("Get-NetNeighbor -AddressFamily IPv4 -IPAddress 192.168.0.*");
var result = ps.Invoke();
```

When this gets run, I get an empty Collection of `PSObjects` from the `Invoke()` method.

I also tried parsing the output through Format-List by doing `Get-NetNeighbor -AddressFamily IPv4 -IPAddress 192.168.0.* | Format-List -Property IPAddress` still to no avail

The only solution I found is using `arp -a`, but I would prefer if I could avoid using that command as parsing Its results are a bit messy

Edit
It errors out because It cannot load the module due to Execution policy not allowing it as it's run on Restricted even though the system is set to RemoteSigned

How do i change the ExecutionPolicy for the code?

Comment: Did you check `ps.HadErrors` and `ps.Streams.Error`? Empty result might be because some error occurs

Comment: From cmd.exe >IPConfig/all  Check if your IP is correct.  Type the Get-Neighbor line directly into a powershell window and see what is returned.   On my pc is used 192.168.1.*

Comment: @jdweng I run all my commands through a normal powershell window before putting them in C# so the command is correct. The Issue was in Execution Policy

Answer (score 1):

It appears that when C# runs powershell through `System.Management.Automation.Powershell` it uses Process Execution Policy. The easiest way to fix that was to add the following bit of code before the command for `Get-NetNeighbor`

```cs
ps.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned");
```

This will set the Execution Policy for that instance of powershell to RemoteSigned aka Execute all local scripts and for scripts from the internet the script has to be signed by a trusted publisher

The command doesn't require administrator privileges to set the ExecutionPolicy for Process scope